# I don't get how copy constructors work in detail

Tags: java, copy-constructor

What is the purpose of this code?

```
public Fraction(Fraction other) {
    num = other.num; 
    denom = other.denom; 
}
```

If you have a constructor like this:

```
public Fraction(int n, int d) {
    num = n;
    denom = d;
}
```

Why do you have to initialize `other.num` to `num` and `other.denom` to `denom`. What is with the syntax of the copy constructor? What is the purpose?

Comment: The purpose is to create an independent copy of the original object, something that cannot be simply achieved by using assignment.

Comment: Mostly copy constructor is useful for deep copy of object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to simply type

```
public Fraction(Fraction other) {
}
```

Java isn't simply going to guess that you want to copy the values of `other` into the new object. Java does not automatically initialize your variables for you like that. For it to be a copy constructor, you still have to manually type out the code that copies the fields from `other` to the object you are creating. Like this:

```
public Fraction(Fraction other) {
    num = other.num; 
    denom = other.denom; 
}
```

The constructor creates a new `Fraction` but it is the code you type inside it that manually performs the "copying" that makes it a "copy constructor" and allows you to do

```
Fraction a = Fraction(4, 20);
Fraction b = new Fraction(a); 
// b has the same values as a but is a different object
```

Of course, if you already have another constructor, a shorter way to make a copy constructor is

```
public Fraction(int n, int d) {
    num = n; 
    denom = d; 
}

public Fraction(Fraction other) {
    this(other.num, other.denom);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is such an enlightenment for.me about constrictors.

Answer (score 4):

It is much more convenient to use.

---

If you have a simple constructor like:

```
public Fraction(int n, int d) {
    num = n;
    denom = d;
}
```

You can copy the instance original with following code:

```
Fraction copy = new Fraction(original.num, original.denom);
```

When using a copy constructor you perform following call:

```
Fraction copy = new Fraction(original);
```

In case you have many parameters this can be much more convenient. What is when you change the arguments of your constructor or your object? Without a copy constructor you have to change all such calls.

---

Noteworthy fact from **M. Prokhorov's** comment:

> There is no special syntax for copy constructors, they are just
>   logical style of implementing a parameterized constructor.

Comment: But what's with the initialization again to num and denom?

Comment: Like syntax of the copy constructor.

Comment: You need to initialize your new instance. You have two independent objects. In my answer those would be `original` and `copy`.

Comment: I mean, original.num will be initialize or assigned to the num on the copy constructor, the same as original.denom to denom. Why? I am sorry if this is becoming a bother to you.

Comment: As I said, because you want to copy an object. Therefore you need to assign the values of your existing object to the new one. If you don't assign those values you will have an empty object and this is not what you want. There are several reasons why you want to copy an object.

Comment: First, you are *not* initializing `original.denom` to `denom`. The opposite - you are initializing `this.denom` with value of `original.denom`. Second, you need this initialization because there is no special syntax for copy constructors, they are just logical style of implementing a parameterized constructor. You can, in fact initialize `this.num = original.denom`, if you want it (whether you should is a different matter entirely, many would consider that a bad style, as it will no longer be a copy constructor, like most of your peers would expect it to be).

Comment: thank you so much guys for answering, i've been trying to figure this out for weeks.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 good reasons for using a copy constructor instead of the constructor passing all parameters :

1. when we have a complex object with many attributes it is convenient to use the copy constructor
2. if we add an attribute to the existing class, then we can just change the copy constructor to take this new attribute into account instead of changing every occurrence of the other constructor

Answer (score 1):

If you have an *instance* of the `Fraction` object like:

```
Fraction fr = new Fraction(1, 2); //represents 1/2
```

Of course you can *copy* it by just assigning it to a new variable:

```
Fraction copy = fr;
```

But now, both `fr` and `copy` point to the same object (same location in memory). If, for some reason, `copy` changes to 1/3, `fr` will change too.
Sometimes you want a completely fresh copy of your original object. That is where it is really handy to write:

```
Fraction copy = new Fraction(fr);
```

Now you can independently manipulate `copy` and `fr` without worrying about unwanted changes in any of them.

You can read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) tutorial to gain more in-depth information on the subject.

Comment: @user707339 Please upvote if you find this answer useful, and accept if it answers your question. Thanks and cheers!